# как удалить куки, очистить куки в xNet c#

Tags: c#, xnet

как удалить куки, очистить куки в xNet c#

Answer (score 1):

```
 HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["currentUser"];
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("currentUser");
 currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
 currentUserCookie.Value = null;
 HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
```